# Can the .NET client send updates in batches during a PushAsync instead of one row at a time?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

We have an Azure Mobile App application using the .NET client library of Azure Mobile Apps.   Whenever we do a PullAsync, the client pulls down data in batches of 50 records per HTTP request/response.   But the PushAsync sends *one PATCH HTTP request per modified row*.   Our use case involves the update of potentially hundreds of rows, which will be slow.

Is it possible to tell Azure Mobile Apps to batch several updates into one HTTP request during a Push?

Another (related) issue is that the Push sends the entire row that was modified, not just the modified fields.   This increases the JSON size unnecessarily.   Is it possible to tell Azure Mobile Apps to only include the modified columns in the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the "batch update" functionality is not directly available.  You can simulate it with a custom API, but have to be careful on sequencing.

The push also needs to send all fields - this is pretty much a requirement of the wire protocol.